# My C do while loop will not execute

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while

My program assignment is to write a looping program that calculates USD to Euros. My code looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)

{
    double USD, euro;
    char again;

    do
    {
    printf("Please enter the amount of USD you want to convert to Euros> ");
    scanf_s("%lf", &USD);

    euro=USD * 0.73209;

    printf("%4.2f USD equals %4.2f Euros.", USD, euro);
    printf("Do you want to convert another amount (y/n)?");
    scanf_s("%c", &again);
    }

    while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y');


    return 0;
}
```

And when I run the program, it executes, allows my to enter a USD value, gives me the correct Euro value, then when prompt for y/n it just exits.

Comment: You might want to try printing the value of `again`.  In this case, it'll help to surround it with characters just in case it's whitespace (or, say, the newline from your previous input).  `printf("again: [%c]\n", again);`

Comment: where would I be adding this in exactly? Instead of saying "..another amount (y/n)?"

Also, in the Do statement or the While statement?

Comment: Well, let's think about this logically.  You want to print out the value of `again` to see what character is being tested in the `while` statement, right?  You want to do that because your `while` statement isn't doing what you think it should.  So it seems to me that the steps you'd follow are:  1.  Read the value into `again`.  2.  *Then* print it out before it gets tested in the `while` statement.  The way you propose is to print the value of `again`, and then read it from the user.  I don't think that will work.

Answer (score 1):

As other folks have explained, your problem is due to `\n` remaining in STDIN.

In order to skip it, just replace

```
scanf_s("%c", &again);
```

with

```
scanf_s(" %c", &again);
```

This is part of `scanf`'s functionality:

> White-space characters: blank (' '); tab ('\t'); or newline ('\n'). A white-space character causes scanf to read, but not store, all consecutive white-space characters in the input up to the next non–white-space character. One white-space character in the format matches any number (including 0) and combination of white-space characters in the input.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwwtf9ch.aspx

For your first `scanf`,

```
scanf(" %lf", &USD);
```

may also help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because that there are stray \r and or \n left in your input stream (stdin), which is read by scanf and gets out of the do while, replace your scanf_s line with

```
while((again = getchar()) != '\n' && again != EOF);
```

if you want to use scanf_s then you can do something like

```
do {scanf_s("%c", &again);}while(again == '\n' || again == '\r');
```

For more information about this check http://c-faq.com/stdio/gets_flush2.html

Comment: Some people use fflush(stdin), which is according to the c standards will have "undefined behavior", hence I won't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use strcmp() here.

```
while ( strcmp(again, 'y') == 0 || strcmp(again, 'Y') == 0 )
```

I'm about two weeks into learning C so sorry if it doesn't work!

Comment: No, `strcmp` is for comparing `char` arrays aka "C string"s.  In this case you need to compare a single `char` variable `again`, so `==` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)

{
    double USD, euro;
    char again;

    do
    {
        printf("Please enter the amount of USD you want to convert to Euros> ");
        scanf_s("%lf", &USD);
        getchar();
        euro=USD * 0.73209;

        printf("%4.2f USD equals %4.2f Euros.", USD, euro);
        printf("Do you want to convert another amount (y/n)?");
        again = getchar();
    }
    while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y');
    return 0;
}
```

It is happening because scanf does not takes whitespace characters. like newline, space etc. when you were pressing enter 'USD' was taking the value and 'again' was taking the newline character. Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

`stdin` (standard input) has one more character you are missing, right after you ask for the USD amount, that character don't simple goes way, as a matter of fact it's waiting for you to pull it out, and that's what you do with the last `scanf`. This happens because you told `scanf` (the first one) to read just a `float` (double) number and nothing else.

To see what's going on, you could check the value of the variable `again` as indiv said. Although it's preferable to print the ASCII value instead of the character itself, because you may not be able to really know for sure if it is an space, new line, tab or any other character of this kind.

instead try this:

```
printf("ASCII: %d, CHAR: %c\n", again, again);
```

Put that line right after the last `scanf`.

Either way, your problem is to find a way to discard that last character. One solution could be reading an string from `stdin` and then using `atof()` to convert that string into a decimal number.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
scanf_s("%c", &again);
```

to

```
scanf_s("%c", &again, 1);
```